# Can a custom LoginModule be a stateful ejb?

Tags: authentication, jboss, jaas, jboss7.x

I am using `jboss-as-7.1.0.Final-SNAPSHOT` and trying to set up custom login module that uses a database.  I followed the instructions in the AS7 documentation to configure a new security domain in standalone.xml, security-domain in jboss-security.xml and security-constraint in web.xml and I set JBoss' logging to TRACE so I can see that my custom login module methods are being successfully invoked (e.g. login(), authenticate()).

I don't want to use manual transaction demarcation in my login module, so it would be great if my login module could be e a stateful ejb.

Taking a look at the [JBoss AS7 : Security Domain Model](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBossAS7SecurityDomainModel) article, which says:

> Just write the FQCN in the code attribute and it should work out of the box.
>
> To place the custom login module class files, you can place them in a jar and put it either:
>
> application classpath of your web archive (war) or ejb jar or enterprise archive (ear)  OR
>      separate module under the modules directory.

It looks like the sky's the limit on where I can place my login module, including within the EJB module of my application.  Does this mean that my custom login module can be a stateful ejb?  I haven't read anything that says, "No."  However when I deploy my login module as stateful ejb injected managed beans and injected EntityManager do not appear to be injected; I get NullPointerException when I try to invoke methods on them.

I took a look at org.jboss.security.auth.spi.DatabaseServerLoginModule, which is provided as one of JBoss' default login modules.  I wanted to see how database access is handled there.  DataSource lookup is via InitialContext e.g.

```
InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
DataSource ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup(dsJndiName);
conn = ds.getConnection();
```

and transactions are all handled manually.  I don't want to use this approach if possible.

Can I use stateful ejb?  Or am I way off base in my approach to this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question was answered on [JBoss Community](https://community.jboss.org/message/717330) as follows:

- Custom login module cannot be a stateful ejb because "the respective lifecycles of a stateful EJB and a login module are quite different," and "login modules are created and used for the duration of a single authentication step and then left to be garbage collected."
- Custom login module can't use CDI, so one cannot inject a managed bean.  One person said that it would be pretty cool if JAAS provided a means to inject a managed bean, and that someone needs to propose an update the JAAS spec. to allow this.